# mac default application for any unknown extension

Tags: macos

I have a series of files that are all text files that i want to open with text editor (let's say Sublime).

The extensions on these files follow the pattern:

- file.sff123
- file.sff124
- file.sff125
- file.sff126

and so on...

Every time i go to open one of these files, the dialog pops up to select the default application for this file type, but since they all have varying extensions, i have to navigate and select the new file type each time. I literally have 1000s of these files and would like to be able to open all of them. Further, i want to be able to open any unknown file with something like Sublime by default. 99% of the time its a random text file... the 1% that it's not i'll "open with".

Is there a way to get Mac to recognize any unknown file extension and open it with an application of my choosing by default?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is possible, but the following (untested) may help you, or someone else work out how to do it.

OSX uses UTIs (Uniform Type Identifiers) to categorise filetypes and map them to applications - and this works in conjunction with *Launch Services* to launch the appropriate application.

I don't have one of your `.sffnnn` files available, but I think you need to run `mdls` on one and see what `kMDItemContentType` is. You can do that like this in Terminal:

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentType somefile.sff123
```

I am  hoping you get the same content type for all your `.sffnnn` files - if you don't, this approach won't work.

You then need to edit your `LaunchServices.plist` file which, I think, is in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` and make an entry corresponding to the filetype you found above that maps to the `sublime` application. I suggest you look in there, or the system-wide version to see how entries look.

Once you get the hang of it, you may be able to do it from the command-line  with a command like:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType=xxxType;LSHandlerRoleAll=xxx.yyy.sublime;}'
```